# sql insert statement with nested select

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to do 1 sql statement (insert) which you duplicate one of the inserting value from another table and another value you hard code?
for eg, profilepic, i want to duplicate the value from another table data. As for displayname, i would like to hard code.
This is my sql statement:

```
  insert into registration (profilePic, displayname) 
    values ( (select profilePic from registration where userId = 143), 'abc'  );
```

Error message from mysql :

```
Error code:1093. You can't specify target table 'registration' for update in from clause.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using subqueries within the values clause will not work. You should use the following query instead:

```
insert into registration (profilePic, displayname) 
select (select profilePic from registration where userId = 143), 'abc'
```